# Excel COUNT Dates in a Month

Tags: excel, date, countif, sumifs

I have a list of dates of birthdays in an excel sheet which I extracted from our site at work. It has over 1000 dates, I would like to set up something that would count how many birthdays there are in Jan.

For e.g

```
01/02/1999
01/01/1981
28/01/2000
12/02/1976
```

for the above the answer would be 2 as there are 2 birthdays in Jan, if that makes sense.

I've tried the below forumala and also many other ones but they all return zero, never #VALUE or any errors, just 0.

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH(A2:A1607)=1,1))
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong, are my dates in the wrong format maybe? (currently in the date format)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

:)

Comment: This should work if you enter your formula using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. If you do it correctly, the formula will be displayed in brackets `{=SUM(IF(MONTH(A2:A1607)=1,1))}`

Comment: @Mister832 It comes back with the value of 501 which is false as there are only 300 of them.. How would I change the formula to get the count for Feb? 1,2?

Comment: Do you allow helper column?

Comment: You would Change it to `{=SUM(IF(MONTH(A2:A1607)=2,1))}` for february. What is result for the 4 columns you've provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work but needs to be entered as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Alternatively, this should work (although I haven't tested it)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A2:A1607)=1))
```

**Edit**

I have now tested this and would recommend the following, which will exclude blank cells, as I found that `=MONTH("")` returned `1`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A2:A1607)=1)*ISNUMBER(A2:A1607))
```

**Edit 2** below also includes the year

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A2:A1607)=1)*(YEAR(A2:A1607)=1997)*ISNUMBER(A2:A1607))
```

Comment: I have the same problem with this one too, it's bringing back 501 when there are only 300 for Jan.. I tried your formula using =3 for March but that comes back with 0 which is definitely wrong.

Comment: Are they all numbers? You can check this by checking if all of your dates are right aligned? If any are sitting left aligned then they are strings and you should multiply them by 1 (`=A1*1`) to change them to number format

Comment: That works! Thank you :) One more question, what If I wanted to count how many January birthdays in the month of 1997? How would that work?

Comment: No problem, I've updated my answer to include this. If this has answered your question please accept and close this question by clicking the green tick mark to the left of this answer

Answer (score 0):

If you allow helper column I think this is the easiest way.

Add a helper column with the formula `=month(<cell>)` then create a pivot table of the data.
Sorry for the swedish, but my Excel is in swedish and that also means I have to write the dates in "swedish".

[image]